# Is there a way to tell if I have MLV or ELV transformers driving my 12V 50W LEDs?

Tags: transformer, low-voltage

Is there a way to tell if I have MLV or ELV transformers driving my 12V 50W LEDs?
I want to dim a small row of ceiling downlights with 3-Way Lutron Maestro dimmers. The actual fixture is a Nora NL-301 downlight can in the ceiling, but I don't know what type of transformer is driving the low voltage.

Comment: What are MLV and ELV transformers? I've never heard of these terms. Is this a DIY question?

Comment: I'm guessing magnetic or electronic,  it it's heavy like metal it's magnetic if it's light like plastic and air it's electronic.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні But all transformers are magnetic...?

Comment: people use terminiology imprecisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ELV = Electronic Low Voltage

MLV = Magnetic Low Voltage.

The latter will be much heavier and somewhat larger and will have almost no components inside, just the transformer. The former type of 'transformer' is actually a switching power supply (not what we'd call a transformer here).

[This particular fixture](https://noralighting.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/NL-301_spec.pdf) comes in both types. I would say if it has the part indicated below (with that appearance) it is of the magnetic type:

[image]

If it looks more like [this](https://noralighting.com/product/nl-301/):

[image]

It is of the electronic type.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I will have to make a slit in my ceiling and poke my cell phone through it to take a picture of it (per your pics above). Thanks again.